# Word(s) for a long-term / cultivated hatred

Tags: word-choice

If I had to combine the word "Odium" with "Cultivation", what word would come closest to explaining that meaning? This is in relation to a certain fantasy / sci-fi book series (the Cosmere) which I'm a fan of.

If anyone wants a bit of a puzzle, I guess they can engage their brains on this if they want! I've thought of words like "Grudge", "Animosity" and the such, but they just don't seem to explain my meaning as well as I like.

Comment: Does the hatred grow over time, or is it a timeless eternal malice? I'm confused by *cultivation* and your comment below that it is a "force of nature".

Comment: Cultivation; the hatred is cultivated, it grows, it has a purpose. In the fantasy series, these are eternal beings with great power that act based on their Intent, which is described by words such as Cultivation or Odium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Grudge* fits, but if it doesn't work it doesn't work.

*To despise* means "to strongly hate" but doesn't necessarily point to a time frame.  Similarly, *detest*, *abominate*, *abhor*, and *loathe*, and others fun words like *execrate*, all indicate *hatred* but not how long you've been hating.

*Bad blood* is an idiom that indicates a long-standing animosity, although not necessarily *hatred*:

> There had been bad blood between Bob and his enemy for many years

You can get metaphorical.  For example a *malignancy* is a growing disease within a body, but figuratively it can refer to ill-will that has *festered* for some time, like a cancer:

> There was a malignancy in Bob's heart, and it had a name: Fred Jones.

Related, a *vendetta* is a serious, long-term campaign of (or related to) vengeance.

> Bob vowed to get his revenge on Fred no matter what it took.  His vendetta would take him across continents and decades.

You can say something is an *anathema*, indicating both strong dislike and outrage.

> The mere mention of the name of the elusive Fred became anathema to him.

Also related, a *nemesis* is someone's arch-enemy.  It does indicate long-standing conflict, but not necessarily *hatred*:

> Bob finally met his nemesis for the last time at the edge of Schroedinger Falls, where they vowed it would not end until one of them was (potentially) dead.

Let me know if I'm getting warm?

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks. I think Malignancy might be the closest out of the bunch to what I'm looking for - it's meant as a representative word for a sort of "god", or a force of nature acting with intent (described by the word).

Answer (score 1):

The word you might be looking for is

> **feud** - a bitter, continuous hostility, especially between two families, clans, etc., often lasting for many years or generations